# How to set an initial value to daterangepicker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, daterangepicker

I have a DateRangePicker as follows:

HTTP:

```
<input id="date" name="date" ng-model="FilesDate" class="form-control"/>
```

JQuery:

```
$('input[name="date"]').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'left'
 });
```

The DateRangePicker works totally fine but when the program initializes, its empty by default. If I remove ng-model, the date initializes properly.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the value of your input:

```
<input value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" id="date" name="date" ng-model="FilesDate" class="form-control" />
```

http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples

Comment: I've tried that, it doesn't work. It's still empty. Also, I want both dates to be today's date, by default.

Comment: Fixed it. Just initialized FilesDate when the application initializes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="date"]').attr('value', '01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018');
```